# Advanced VS Regex Find/Replace: use string inside <h1> to add another <td> below each occuring <td>

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, find-replace

An example describes it better. Suppose you have a structure like this:

```
<h1>TITLE OF HEAD 1</h1>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 1, AFTER HEAD 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 2, AFTER HEAD 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 3, AFTER HEAD 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 4, AFTER HEAD 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 5, AFTER HEAD 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h1>TITLE OF HEAD 2</h1>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 6, AFTER HEAD 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h1>TITLE OF HEAD 3</h1>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 7, AFTER HEAD 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 8, AFTER HEAD 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 9, AFTER HEAD 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 10, AFTER HEAD 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h1>TITLE OF HEAD 4</h1>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 11, AFTER HEAD 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 12, AFTER HEAD 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And with regex, the outcome should be:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 1, AFTER HEAD 1</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 2, AFTER HEAD 1</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 3, AFTER HEAD 1</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 4, AFTER HEAD 1</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 5, AFTER HEAD 1</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h1>TITLE OF HEAD 2</h1>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 6, AFTER HEAD 2</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h1>TITLE OF HEAD 3</h1>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 7, AFTER HEAD 3</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 8, AFTER HEAD 3</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 9, AFTER HEAD 3</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 10, AFTER HEAD 3</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h1>TITLE OF HEAD 4</h1>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 11, AFTER HEAD 4</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="one">ITEM 12, AFTER HEAD 4</td>
            <td class="two">TITLE OF HEAD 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I've tried so far:

Now getting the strings inside the `<h1>` is easy:

find: `(<h1>)(.*?)(</h1>)`
replace: `$2`

Then I tried:

find: `(<h1>)(.*?)(</h1>)(\n|.)*?(<td class="one">.*?</td>)`
replace: `$5<td class="two">$2</td>`

which works, but the other tags are removed as well, so I've modified it:

find `(<h1>)(.*?)(</h1>)((\n|.)*?)(<td class="one">.*?</td>)`
replace: `$4$6<td class="two">$2</td>`

Each string of a new `h1` will be used for the `tds` that occur afterwards until a new `h1` occurs, which will then be used - the problem is this only works for each **first** `td`after each `h1`, not all `tds`.

Could somebody tell me what needs to be added to the regex for this to work?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't match the same substring several times. That's why your approach doesn't work. A workaround consists to use a lookbehind that doesn't consume the substring you are interested by. You can do that: https://regex101.com/r/nwQtZM/1 but you need a second pass (with a more simple pattern) to remove the h1 tags.

Comment: Also possible in one pass: https://regex101.com/r/nwQtZM/2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
<h1>([^<]*)<\/h1>\s*\n([\w\W]*?)(([^\n\S]*)<td\s.*?<\/td>(\n))(?=\s*<\/tr>)|(?<=<h1>([^<]*)<\/h1>[\w\W]*?)(([^\n\S]*)<td\s.*?<\/td>(\n))(?=\s*<\/tr>)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/ioSZxk/2).

*Replace with*: `$2$3$4$7$8<td class="two">$1$6</td>$5$9`.

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <h1>                     '<h1>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^<]*                    any character except: '<' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  </h1>                    '</h1>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w\W]*?                 any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), non-word characters (all
                             but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\n\S]*                 any character except: '\n' (newline),
                               non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t,
                               \f, and " ") (0 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <td                      '<td'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </td>                    '</td>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \5:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </tr>                    '</tr>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <h1>                     '<h1>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \6:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^<]*                    any character except: '<' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \6
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </h1>                    '</h1>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w\W]*?                 any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), non-word characters (all
                             but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \7:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \8:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\n\S]*                 any character except: '\n' (newline),
                               non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t,
                               \f, and " ") (0 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <td                      '<td'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </td>                    '</td>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \9:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \9
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </tr>                    '</tr>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: The above regex doesn't handle newlines in the right way for vscode.  See https://regex101.com/r/Xi8MKz/1 generally you just have to add `\r?` or `\r` in front of the `\n`'s.  Compare the newline handling to Casimir's which is correct.

Comment: I have tested in my Visual Studio Code and it works.

Comment: @PoulBak I see [it works](https://imgur.com/a/KP27Lge). Note VSCode does not use .NET regex engine in the search and replace feature, it uses the ECMAScript 2018 compliant engine.

Comment: My bad, I thought VS and VS Code used the same engine.